# In Erlang how can I compile a module from within a module?

Tags: erlang

I have tried :

```
c(module_name).
```

: but this only works from the shell, and gives an error when I try to run it from within a module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want exactly that behaviour, `c:c(module_name)` will call the same function called by the shell. I would hesitate to put code that calls user_default (`c`) functions in production code, so you might want to look at [the source for the function](http://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/c.erl#L70) and replicate it in your own code so you don't get bitten by a behaviour change in a future erlang release.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look to the compile module and to the compile:file/2 function in specific.